# Как преобразовать строку в словать

Tags: python, dict, строки

Есть строка `dic = "{"pos": 7, 4: 5, "go": 2, "tpjc": None}"` как её преобразовать в словарь? Пробовал `dic = dict(dic)` вышла ошибка `ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required` в интернете ничего не мог найти

Comment: `dic = "{"pos": 7, "4": 5, "go": 2}" import json json.loads(dic)`

Answer (score 2):

Только поменять внешние (или внутренние) кавычки, сейчас у вас код не валидный.

```
from ast import literal_eval

dic = '{"pos": 7, 4: 5, "go": 2, "tpjc": None}'
dic = literal_eval(dic)
print(type(dic), dic)
```

Вывод:

```
<class 'dict'> {'pos': 7, 4: 5, 'go': 2, 'tpjc': None}
```

Через `json` обычно лучше, но в данном случае формат не подходящий для него.

Comment: Спасиб я вообще так события из event pygame обрабатывать хочу но type не работает он мне выдаёт либо 769 либо 768 я кстати пишу код на телефоне прога называется pydroid